# how to auto convert nil to [NSNull null] when add it to array(dict)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have some values need to be added to an array (using `initWithObjects`), and encode to JSON string later.

As everyone knows, when array meet a `nil`, it will stop read next value.

As convention of JSON Array, the nil should be act as an null in ordered position.

Should I check every value, and manually convert it to `[NSNull null]` before add it to array?

Comment: if I were you, I would kill the person who sends `null` value via JSON, but that is my personal opinion only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I check every value, and manually convert it to [NSNull null] before add it to array?

Yes. You can create a simple helper method/function:

```
id GuardJSONElement(id arg) { return arg ? arg : [NSNull null]; }
```

and then:

```
[array addObject:GuardJSONElement(something)];
```

Comment: @Kane like so: `NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: GuardJSONElement(p1), GuardJSONElement(p2), nil];`.

Comment: If you don't want to create a helper method/function another way to do it is to use the ternary operator directly inline (which is what a good compiler will do with the helper function anyway): `[array addObject:(something?something:[NSNull null])]`