# Adding key values to nsdictionary misses keys

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have been adding key value pairs to nsdictionary like this

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{key1:value1, key2:value2};
```

if value1 is not found, the app crashes. So, I implemented the other way of doing it

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value1,key1,value2,key2,nil];
```

In this case, if value1 is not found, dict does not go further and does not have key2. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Why can't I set nil to NSDictionary value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008365/ios-why-cant-i-set-nil-to-nsdictionary-value)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of that question. It is a different question and different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDictionary` (as well as `NSArray`) cannot store `nil`, because they expect an object.

A solution would be to use [NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnull) or to not store the value at all. In the later case the `objectForKey:` method will return `nil` if it does not find the value for the given key, which might be want you want.

In the second code example the problem that it is not going further is that this method expects an `nil`-terminated list so it just stops at the first nil as it thinks this is the end.

You can use `setValue:forKey:`, this will just remove the value for the key if the value is `nil`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008450/3386893). But therefore it need to be a mutable array and you have to go through all values one by one.

Another solution would be to guard each value with a check, e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10681633/3386893).

Comment: I have just given an example. In actual case there are 10-20 keys that I am storing, how can I check for everyone to be null.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   [dict2 setValue:value1 forKey:key1];
   [dict2 setValue:value2 forKey:key2];
   [dict2 setValue:value3 forKey:key3];

    NSLog(@"dict2 - %@",dict2);
```

Works like a charm !!!

Comment: This is what I edited into my answer after you added the comment :)

Comment: @Nef10 answer makes perfect sense. you should accept the answer.